# How to use create_ffmpeg_player in discord.py

Tags: python, subprocess, discord.py

I can't use create_ffmpeg_player() in discord.py

I'm creating discord tts bot that only work on certain voice channels.
so I use gTTS to make a mp3 file and it works well
but when I play the mp3 file by create_ffmpeg_player(), Console says Can't Find File!

please help me

here is my code about create_ffmpeg_player

```
vc = client.voice_client_in(message.server) 

player = await vc.create_ffmpeg_player('dts.mp3')

player.start()
```

i used voice_client_in for get voiceclient in vc

this is my error code

```
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\discord\voice_client.py", line 431, in create_ffmpeg_player
    p = subprocess.Popen(args, stdin=stdin, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=stderr)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\subprocess.py", line 709, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\subprocess.py", line 997, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] 지정된 파일을 찾을 수 없습니다/*(The specified file could not be found.)*/

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 307, in _run_event
    yield from getattr(self, event)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "dts.py", line 76, in on_message
    player = await vc.create_ffmpeg_player('dts.mp3')
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\discord\voice_client.py", line 434, in create_ffmpeg_player
    raise ClientException('ffmpeg/avconv was not found in your PATH environment variable') from e
discord.errors.ClientException: ffmpeg/avconv was not found in your PATH environment variable
```

if it works well there must be played the voice mp3 file!
but it just occurs error

Error says file could not be found but there is an mp3 file in the directory where the .py file is located.

please help me to make my bot

Comment: Do you have ffmpeg installed and available in your PATH?  This isn't a step the discord.py installation can do for you, you would have to have done it yourself.

Comment: Oh I don't read last sentence I download ffmpeg and it works well THANK YOU!